# Knockout.js default event binding vs custom bindings using jQuery event delegation .on() - performance and gains?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Is there some performance or other gains using custom binding and $.on() to react on human interaction on some list of data with ~500 rows?

This question came to mind cause i noticed that knockout events are attached to element using bind(), that means that they are on every click button, or am i wrong?

I have two samples

First - http://jsfiddle.net/dzjosjusuns/yStt7/ - event attached to child item

```
<div data-bind="text:head.id"></div>
<div id="container" data-bind="foreach:head.rows">
    <div class="item">
        <button data-bind="click:$root.head.deleteRow">remove</button>
        <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Second - http://jsfiddle.net/dzjosjusuns/NN3h8/ - event is attached to parent only with custom binding

```
<div data-bind="text:head.id"></div>
<div id="container" data-bind="foreach:head.rows, onRowDelete:head.deleteRow">
    <div class="item">
        <button>remove</button>
        <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Custome binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.onRowDelete = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $('#container').on('click', '.item button', function (event) {
            valueAccessor().call(viewModel.head, ko.dataFor(event.target), event.target);
        });
    }
};
```

So, is there some point in doing such custom bindings?

Comment: Check out this post: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/11/revisit-event-delegation-in-knockout-js.html

Comment: I once had a page with thousands of click bindings. Using jQuery event delegation on container or RPN's plugin shaved noticeable amount of init time (from 100s to 1000s of milliseconds). So, there are performance gains.

Comment: Also have a look here: http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2012/11/29/loading-knockout-view-models-from-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some performance or other gains using custom binding and
>   $.on() to react on human interaction on some list of data with ~500
>   rows?

Yes. Using the default event bindings, Knockout will attach a handler to each of the 500 rows.

As @nemesv stated, you can use Ryan Neimeyer's [Knockout.DelegatedEvents](http://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-delegatedEvents) library which will take advantage of event bubbling to efficiently attach handlers to DOM element events.